# Mockito does not return mockValue when mockito class passed as a dependency

Tags: android, mockito

It is a bit tough the explain the situation actually. I mock a class and pass it to another class's constructor. Then, I create the first class and call the first class's method under the second class's method, it returns null. Please check below:

```
class A {
    public String getName() {
        return "Something";
    }
}

class B {
    private A a;
    public B(A insA) {
        this.a = insA;
    }
    public String createName() {
        return a.getName(); // when this is called, returns null.
    }
}

class TestB {
    public testBSomething() {
        A mockA = mock(A.class);
        when(mockA.getName()).thenReturn("Somevalue");
        B insB = new B(mockA);
        assertEqual("SomeValue", insB.createName()); // insB.createName() = null which should return "Somevalue"
    }
}
```

I also tried doReturn, thenAnswer and spy variations, but no luck. Probably, I miss something, but I could not find. If anyone has any idea, I will really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestB {

    @Mock
    A mockA;

    @InjectMocks
    B insB;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        insB = new B(mockA);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBSomething() {
        when(mockA.getName()).thenReturn("SomeValue");
        Assert.assertEquals("SomeValue", insB.createName()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I noticed that running with Mockito fixes the issue, but I need to run with Roboelectric in order to use some org.JSON library. Do you have any tip to run multiple test runner if it is possible?

Comment: No issue, same code just change the runner with Robo...runner, and no, multiple runner doesn't support